# Previous Cells remain after using collectionView.reloadData?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, reload

I have all of my view stylings in the method

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    displayDataForIndexPath()
}
```

Which is called when I need to reload data in my `ViewController`. My `ViewController` has a `CollectionView` that I need to refresh.

I've added `collectionview.reloadData()` to my `displayDataForIndexPath()` method. However, all the previous cells remain, instead of disappearing, so the new cells stack on top of the old ones. What is the proper method to remove those old cells so the `CollectionView` reloads properly?

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to delete your datasource

in your cellForItemAtIndexPath you should not add more controls to the cell. it should be only done one time on creation of the cell.

as the name states when you normaly get your cell: `reuse` and that means it reuses from the last state it displayed in the collection.